# Cannot get a cookie using ajax request and jqXHR object

Tags: jquery, ajax

I made an ajax request .I need to access `Cookie` or `Set-Cookie` properties. I tried to get cookie from headers of `jqXHR` object as `jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()`. Did not showed any headers relating to cookies. Why? How to get `Cookie` or `Set-Cookie` properties?

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                    url: 'MYurl,
                    success: function(data) {
                        // success, do work
                        alert(jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                    },
                    error: function(data) {
                        // error, handle failure
                    }
                });
```

UPDATE1:
Why Firefox classify as `Rejected Cookies` the Cookies received by Ajax?
[image] 
UPDATE2:
[4.7.3 The getResponseHeader() method](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getresponseheader%28%29-method)

> Returns the header field value from the response of which the field
>   name matches header, unless the field name is Set-Cookie or
>   Set-Cookie2.

Comment: Those cookies are probably HttpOnly, which is why you can't read them; otherwise, evaluate `document.cookie`.

Comment: Is there a way to specify some other type of `Cookie` so it could be easily accessed?

Comment: Do you really need the cookie though? Why do you need it?

Comment: I need to Log in and keep the session for current user using ajax.

Comment: There's no need, when you make Ajax request the cookie gets sent as well, automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at this jQuery Plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

I' ve use it before with a node.js socket application and it works great!

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it - works fine but first I need to get a cookie using ajax. So far I cannot get one because `jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders()` does not have `Cookie` or `Set-Cookie` headers. How can I get it working?